# Kafka Topic Avro Key not populated from Cassandra Source Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra, apache-kafka-connect

I have a Kafka Topic that has the following Avro Key Schema:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "onboardingStatusKey",
  "namespace": "onboarding",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "time_created",
      "type": "long",
      "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
    },
    {
      "name": "local_enterprise_id",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "source_request_reference",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "onboarding_request_id",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "system_code",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ],
  "version": "1"
}
```

I also have a table within Cassandra that has these fields (plus a few others). I'm looking for a Source Connector that will move the data from the Cassandra table to my Kafka topic.

My Source Connector config is:

```
{
    "name": "cassandra-source-{{TableName}}-3",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.source.CassandraSourceConnector",
        "tasks.max": "2",
        "connect.cassandra.contact.points": "{{CassandraContactPoints}}",
        "connect.cassandra.port": "{{CassandraContactPort}}",
        "connect.cassandra.ssl.enabled": "true",
        "connect.cassandra.trust.store.path": "/trusted-clusters.jks",
        "connect.cassandra.trust.store.password": "{{TruststorePWD}}",
        "connect.cassandra.trust.store.type": "JKS",
        "connect.cassandra.username": "{{CassandraUsername}}",
        "connect.cassandra.password": "{{CassandraPassword}}",
        "connect.cassandra.key.space": "{{Keyspace}}",

        "connect.cassandra.import.mode": "incremental",
        "connect.cassandra.kcql": "INSERT INTO {{TopicName}} SELECT * FROM {{TableName}} PK time_created INCREMENTALMODE=TIMESTAMP WITHKEY(time_created, local_enterprise_id, source_request_reference, onboarding_request_id, system_code)",

        "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "https://{{SchemaUsername}}:{{SchemaPassword}}@kafka-schema.{{SchemaURL}}.cnodes.io:8085",
        "key.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source": "URL",

        "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "https://{{SchemaUsername}}:{{SchemaPassword}}@kafka-schema.{{SchemaURL}}.cnodes.io:8085",
        "value.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source": "URL",

        "errors.tolerance": "all",
        "errors.log.include.messages": true,
        "errors.log.enable": true
    }
}
```

The rows from the table are being sent to the topic but the key is missing from each record (just the value section appears)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

> Disclaimer: I have no experience with this connector

You seem to be missing a [`WITHKEY`](https://docs.lenses.io/5.0/integrations/connectors/stream-reactor/sources/cassandrasourceconnector/) part of your query for selecting one-to-many fields to write as the record key.

Keep in mind that source connectors create their own Avro schemas, and will not use the one you've pre-defined outside of compatibility checks (if enabled)

Comment: tried again by adding WITHKEY to my kcql but this did not do anything more.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you changed